# Is there a way to log a failed docker load?

Tags: docker

I am trying to install a Docker image which I have created myself.

I do

```sh
docker load < mariadb_mymariadb.tar
Loaded image: mariadb_mymariadb:latest
```

As you can see docker returns `Loaded image: mariadb_mymariadb:latest`.

But when I do

```sh
docker ps
```

the container list ist remains empty:

```sh
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

So, something must have gone wrong somewhere down the line.

Using `docker logs mariadb_mymariadb` obviously doesn't work, because it only logs containers which are actually up and running.

Does Docker log errors of failed installations somewhere?

Comment: Ooops no. Yeah, and now I get my errors, great!!! Thanks a lot. Please move your comment into an answer, so I can check it of a as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the `image` is loaded successfully but `docker ps` doesn't provide any output because it's actually a command for listing "up and running" containers.

So, you will have to first use `docker run ... mariadb_mymariadb:latest ...` in order to `create` a new container and actually `start` it.